# SQL Server - trying to work out a SELECT DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2016

I have a simple three-column table which shows the date our system last checked a certain url, and the id number associated with that website.

If I were to run the following query:

```
SELECT
SourceId,
Url,
Date
FROM Table1
```

I end up with the following results:

```
SourceId   Url                  Date
1          www.google.com/abc   2017-10-21
1          www.google.com/def   2017-10-22
1          www.google.com/ghi   2017-10-18
2          www.yahoo.com/123    2017-09-20
2          www.yahoo.com/456    2017-09-27
2          www.yahoo.com/789    2017-10-01
3          www.youtube.com/xyz  2017-07-08
3          www.youtube.com/prs  2017-08-01
3          www.youtube.com/mno  2017-07-16
```

What I need is only one record per source id, and for it to be the most recent date associated with that source id; then finally, I'd want the entire list sorted by source id in ascending order.  Therefore the results would look like this:

```
SourceId   Url                  Date
1          www.google.com/def   2017-10-22
2          www.yahoo.com/789    2017-10-01
3          www.youtube.com/prs  2017-08-01
```

I know I have to end the query with `ORDER BY SourceId`. It's the one record per source at the most recent date I'm having trouble with.  I thought I should be using DISTINCT on SourceId but it's not working seemingly because it's looking for duplicate values in the other columns?

**EDIT - updated the results which had incorrect values in the URL column.**

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise

Comment: Why you have `www.google.com/abc` in the result and not `www.google.com/def`?

Comment: @RadimBača thank you I just edited that and fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `row_number` window function to query only one row per id:

```
SELECT   [SourceId], [Url], [Date]
FROM     (SELECT [SourceId], [Url], [Date],
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SourceId]
                                    ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
          FROM   Table1) t
WHERE    rn = 1
ORDER BY [SourceId] ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
 SELECT
   SourceId,
   Url,
   Date
 FROM Table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM table1 t2
   WHERE t1.SourceId = t2.SourceId and t2.date > t1.date
 )
 ORDER BY SourceId
```

Comment: @MartinSmith true, I did not noticed

Comment: If there are N > 1 records with the same `SourceId` that also share the same `Date`, and no other records with that `SourceId` having a later `Date`, then this query will return all N of them. OP specifies at most one record per `SourceId`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WITH TIES clause in concert with Row_Number()

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By SourceID Order By Date Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
SourceId    Url                 Date
1           www.google.com/def  2017-10-22
2           www.yahoo.com/789   2017-10-01
3           www.youtube.com/prs 2017-08-01
```

> **EDIT Test**

```
/*
Drop Table #Temp
Select N
      ,S = newid()
 Into  #Temp
 From (Select Top 1000000 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2) A
*/

 Select Top 1 with ties * 
  from  #Temp
  Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By left(S,2) Order by N Desc)

Select *
 From (
        Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By left(S,2) Order by N Desc)
         From  #Temp
      ) A
 Where RN=1
```

Results

```
Run With Ties   RN
1   1.83        5.444
2   1.9         5.444
3   1.913       6.374
4   1.957       5.8
5   1.833       6.244

Avg 1.8866      5.8612
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, WITH TIES is new to me.  I am curious to read up on this and try this one.

Comment: @Stpete111 I like this approach... no subquery or extra field.

Comment: I would not recommend this for serious use. Instead of calculating the row number and then a simple filter to drop all greater than one it will likely calculate the row numbers then sort the whole result.

Comment: @MartinSmith Not sure I agee, I've seen virtually the same results on both large and small tables.   That said, you've got me curious and will run some benchmarks.

Comment: @MartinSmith Did a quick test on 1MM rows and the WITH TIES averaged 1.88 seconds while the subquery with RN averaged 5.86 seconds.

Comment: Can you paste your data setup script and queries somewhere?

Comment: No repro for me - I've tried a couple of times and both times `WITH TIES` came out worse. 2nd run https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nd6H.png

Comment: @MartinSmith Run them individually.  You'll see.  Replicated my results +/- ms

Comment: Nope doesn't make any difference for me - maybe for you the extra cost pushes it into a parallel plan?

Comment: @MartinSmith Huh.  Added my stats image as well   So I guess the real answer is "It may depend"  :)

Comment: Well it looks like the first one is parallel (cpu time > elapsed time) and the second one isn't. So that is probably just a testament to the higher estimated cost rather than anything else. If you run them both at the same degree of parallelism I would expect you to find the `WITH TIES` slower

Answer (score 1):

T-Sql:-

```
  SELECT * FROM  
( SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SOURCEID] ORDER BY [Date] desc) AS ROW_NUMBER FROM [TABLE1] ) AS ROWS
  WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 1
```

Output:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mureinik's answer shows the way that I would have done it, and I also upvoted John Cappelletti's answer because I think it shows an interesting alternate construction, even though the comments on it raise some performance concerns.

I just wanted to add a few things. First, your supposition as to why `DISTINCT` isn't working is correct: if you write a `SELECT` statement with a `DISTINCT` in it, the `DISTINCT` applies to *all* of the fields in your select list, not just one. When you need a set of distinct values *plus* some additional information about them, a window function like `row_number()` should be your first thought.

Second, while `DISTINCT` is occasionally useful, I think it's a feature that gets misused a lot. When I'm reading through or revising an existing query and I see a `DISTINCT`, I immediately wonder whether the original author of the query really needed it, or whether he/she used it to cover up some questionable logic elsewhere in the query, such as the use of an inner or outer join where a [semi-join](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/19/introduction-to-joins/) would have been more appropriate. Most often, the latter ends up being the case. When you're considering writing a `SELECT DISTINCT`, it's worthwhile to stop and ask yourself whether a better solution might exist, using the features shown in the other answers to this question.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information Joe.  What I am doing now is trying all 4 of the suggestions below this one to see which one performs the best.  As you may imagine, the example I gave in my question is a very simplified version of the real data I'm dealing with (over 2 million records) so whichever of the below performs the best will be the one I'll mark as the answer.